# Need a login that will hit AD and give me back a list of roles

Tags: active-directory

I need to come up with a way for users in a domain to hit a page, and for it to give me back a list of their roles in AD.  If they don't have windows credentials, I'd like it to prompt them for an id/password/domain, hit LDAP, and return their roles if any.

The reason for this is 50% of the users are on Windows machines logged in, 50% of the users are on what amounts to dumb terminals with no AD credentials.

I need the roles because I have to parse together a url to send to a third party company's token login.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your site to use Windows Integrated Authentication and people in teh domain (and where your site is in their Local Intranet zone) will pass-thru. Other users will get prompted and IIS will handle the authentication to AD.

You can use the `WindowsIdentity` class' `Group` property to get the user's groups. Something like this:

```
WindowsIdentity current = ((WindowsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).Identity;
```